# Why doesn't my input work inside an if condition

Tags: python

I don't know why my inputs inside the if condition don't work when I run the code. Any help would be appreciated:

```
V = input("Ingresar A, si quieres calcular el ahorro anual, o M, si quieres 
calcular el ahorro mensual")
def M_o_A(V):
  if V == "A":
   P = input("Ingrese el porcentaje que quiere calcular: ")
   S = input("Ingrese su sueldo mensual: ")
   T = (P * S / 100) * 12
   print "Si usted ahorra el ",P,"% de su sueldo por un año, tendras 
",T,"pesos."

  elif V == "M":
     PM = input("Ingrese el porcentaje que quiere calcular: ")
     SM = input("Ingrese su sueldo mensual: ")
     TM = PM * SM / 100
     print "Si usted ahorra el ",PM,"% de su sueldo, tendras ",TM,"pesos."
```

Comment: Which errore are you getting?

Comment: I don't see a call to `M_o_A`. Your conditionals are in the function `M_o_A`.

Comment: I dont get an error, the thing is the inputs dont make the question when I run the code

Answer (score 2):

You're defining but not calling the M_o_A function. At the end of your script

```
M_o_A(V)
```

Anyway, I fear there are other errors. Please, show us the output

Comment: What do you mean by defining? Im new in python and I dont understand much the def thing.

Comment: And what are the outputs? What I posted was all the code I had.

Comment: You need to define a function before be able to call it. You're defining it, and that's ok, it's what the function does, but you're never calling it, so it's useless.

Comment: The output, I mean what happens when you run the program from a terminal, to understand what's going on